# VBA Run-time error ‘-2147417848 (80010108)’ but only with large data sets

Tags: excel, vba

Each of the datasheets has a header row and the first row has a number of formulas. The code is supposed to first delete the data in each sheet except for the header row and formula row. Next, it copies the formula from the first row of each sheet and pastes it according to the number of rows determined from the data entry page. The code works fine for a few hundred rows of data but I get the below error message

> "Run-time error ‘-2147417848 (80010108)’:
> Method ‘PasteSpecial’ of object ‘Range’ failed"

when there are a few thousand rows of data.
This is driving me crazy and I have no idea how to fix it

This is the VBA code:

```vb
Sub FillWithFormula1()
    Worksheets("CALCULATE").Unprotect "pass"
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    lastRow = Worksheets("DATA ENTRY PAGE").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    For Each ws In Worksheets(Array("CALCULATE", "NUTRIENTSORT", "INSECT TYPE SORT", "FUNGUS GROUP SORT", "WEEDSORT", "BACTERIASORT", "VIRUSSORT", "NEMATODESORT", "MITESORT", "BIRDSORT", "MAMMALSORT", "PHYTOPLASMASORT", "FUNGUS", "BACTERIA", "NEMATODE", "VIRUS", "PHYTOPLASMA", "INSECT", "NUTRIENT", "WEED", "WATERMOULD", "BIRD", "MAMMAL", "MOLLUSC", "MITE", "OTHER", "UNKNOWN", "ENVIRONMENT", "aphid", "Fruitfly", "mealybug", "leafminer", "cricket", "mole cricket", "scale", "thrip", "stemborer", "beetles", "whitefly", "caterpillars", "cutworms", "termites", "rust", "smut", "botrytis", "powderymildew", "dampingoff", "bug", "jassid", "Mirid", "gallmidge", "weevil", "nitrogen", "phosphate", "potassium", "calcium", "boron", "Iron", "zinc", "molybdenum", "sulphur", "downymildew", "lateblight", "clubroot", "Bananaweevil", "FALLARMYWORM"))
        With ws
            .Range("A3:AN100000").ClearContents        
            .Range("A2:AN2").Copy            
             If lastRow = 1 Then                        
                 lastRow = lastRow + 1
             End If            
             .Range("A2:AN" & lastRow).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulas
             .Range("A2:AN" & lastRow).PasteSpecial xlFormats    
        End With
    Next ws
    
    For Each Rng In Worksheets("CALCULATE").Range("A2:AM" & lastRow)
        If Rng.HasFormula Then
            Rng.Locked = True    
        Else
            Rng.Locked = False
        End If    
    Next Rng
    
    Worksheets("CALCULATE").Protect "pass", AllowFiltering:=True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

The error is in the line:

```
.Range("A2:AN" & lastRow).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulas
```

Comment: it does not say which worksheet. The error is in the line: .Range("A2:AN" & lastRow).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulas. I can't understand why it works for small data-sets but fall over with larger ones

Comment: OK the worksheet on which it fails changes depending on the number of rows of data in the DATA ENTRY PAGE it has failed on INSECT TYPE SORT, NUTRIENT SORT and  WATERMOULD. The last few times I have run the script on large datasets Excel has fallen over and closed itself down not allowing me to see the sheet name

Comment: This is a speculation, but this error could be due to the fact that your code is trying to paste into cells that are being calculated or used in the process of calculating other cells. When the number of cells is small, the calculation is fast enough that it doesn't interfere with VBA, but with larger data range, it might cause issues. You could try to turn off automatic calculation with `Application.Calculation = xlManual` at the beginning of your code (and reset it to `xlAutomatic` at the end of your code) to see if that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion it made sense as there is something happening that is linked to the size of the dataset. Unfortunately, it has not solved the problem. Anymore  suggestions gratefully received

Comment: Unfortunately, I was not able to replicate the problem, so without more information on the content of your workbook, it's going to be difficult to come up with potential solutions.

Comment: I really appreciate your interest and help with this problem. Is there anyway that I could share my file with you?

Comment: Before sharing the file, could you confirm (by editing your question), what version of Excel you are using just in case this issue is version specific?

Comment: If your file doesn't contain any sensitive information, any file sharing service that can create a shareable link can be used. However, make sure that you've tried to reduce the complexity of your spreadsheet to the minimum amount of complexity needed to reproduce the issue (See also [MCVE article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for details).